# Is it possible to write a regex to extract java package?

Tags: java, regex, package

Is it possible to write a regex, which extractst the package path in a .java file?

Something like this:

```
package java.awt.event;
// java code
```

to this

```
java.awt.event
```

which i than can resolve to the folder location?

```
java/awt/event/
```

I don't know which characters a package can have, or if it's possible to add more than one package.

Comment: You can only have one package... Why do you need this from Java source?

Comment: well, i don't want the user to say it to me (usability reason) so i thought we could extract them. I need the right file structure to compile the java files ;)

Comment: yes, it is possible.  what have you tried so far?

Comment: i've tried some of the basic string operations. wanted to split the file in lines and have a loock for package there, i'm not so familiar with regex, but i thougt this would be a much nicer way to do this!

Comment: @PhilippSpieß If you need to extract package information from a Java file's source code in order to compile it correctly... something's amiss, or you didn't really ask the question you want the answer to.

Comment: Well I want my customer to upload an Interface which we need to compile. The customer can decide which namespace the file has. To compile it, i have to create the right folder structure, but i just want the customer to upload one file (the .java file) and don't want them to inter the namespace, because it's already in the .java file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
"package\\s+([a-zA_Z_][\\.\\w]*);"
```

There can only be one package at the beginning of a java file. Only word characters and "." are allowed.

```
"package\\s+" => the work "package" followed by at least one space
"("           => start of capture
"[a-zA-Z_]"   => first character of package (doesn't include numeric digits)
"[\\.\\w]*"   => any number of word characters (a-zA-Z0-9_) plus the "." character
")"           => end of capture
";"           => end of line
```

Really this is not the best since it does not enforce that the first character of each folder not be a digit however it will work without fully enforcing rules. This being the case the following might be easier:

```
"package\\s+([\\w\\.]+);"
```

Comment: digits are allowed (just not in as first character)

Comment: Yeah, but my point is that \\w allows digits. So the correct one would be "([a-zA-Z_]([\\w\\.]*....". I see where mine is wrong too though, so good catch. ;)

Comment: It's not easy for me to decide which one to mark, but i guess it yours since you're the first and edited your answer. ;D

Comment: Hi! I found your answer the best one so far, would you mind explaining the regex, I am sort of lost :(

Comment: This answer is not completely valid:
1) The package name may contain non-ascii characters
2) *by convention* the first part only consists of lowercase ascii characters

Comment: @rmuller good points (although I think it should match any valid package name not just those that are conventional), do you have a suggestion on a better regex?

Comment: technically correct: [\\p{IsAlphabetic}_]+(?:\\.[\\p{IsAlphabetic}_0-9]+)* By convention: [a-z_]+(?:\\.[\\p{IsLowercase}_0-9]+)* Also see Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Finally (just tested :)) this seems the best regex technical wise (obeying the conventions): 
<br/>
\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}+(?:\\.\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}+)*

Answer (score 2):

you can have only 1 package declaration and allowed syntax is the same as normal identifiers

```
"package ([\\w&&\\D]([\\w\\.]*[\\w])?);"
```

capture group 1 will have the package replace the . with file separators and you're there

Comment: I believe \\w includes \\d. \\w is any valid word character, which includes digits.

Comment: @JohnB yeah I notices fixed it (note that my regex also doesn't allow . as last char)

Comment: Yeah, I think yours is better than mine. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This regexp works perfectly :

```
package\\s([a-zA-Z]\\w*)(\\.[a-zA-Z]\\w*)*;"\
```

to match :

- "package"
- whitespace
- package definition starting with a non digit character
- any sub package definition
- ";"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is delayed but i would like to contribute this one i made which works reasonably well specifically for Android package names convention.

```
  (^[a-z]+[.][a-z]+[.][a-z]+($|[.][a-z]+$))
```